# Alternative for onchange event that will fire first

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `select` element on my Site and am firing an event in JS/jQuery when that changes like so:

```
$("select#quantity").on("change", function(){
    //do stuff
})
```

However, you either need to click out of the select box again or wait a split second after the change has been made for this event to happen.

Is there a way to trigger this sooner? Like as soon as they choose an option without clicking back out of the select box.

Comment: The `change` event fires as soon as you click on another option, or navigate to another option using your keyboard. You don't need to click anywhere else to fire it.

Comment: The above is true. It sounds like your issue is due to flawed logic, or a performance problem somewhere. In which case we'd need to see a much more complete sample of your JS and HTML in order to help you debug it.

Comment: Try using the `input` event.  I know it works on text fields, but I've never tried it on a select.

Comment: the issue is that the function is submitting a form to update the quantity of products and if a user on my site hits continue on that page before the form submits it just goes through as the original quantity not what they updated. I changed it to a mouseleave function and it seems to be working better

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yeah, so you can use the `input` event which happens as soon as the value of the input changes.

```js
$('#quantity').on('input', function (e) {
  console.log(this.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="quantity">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: So does the `change` event, so I'm not sure what problem this would solve. The only difference would be that `input` fires before `change`, so if you had multiple handlers bound to `change`, this would affect their order (http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/om6d5L9r/). It could be argued that is a flawed situation to be in in the first place, though.

Comment: True, it appears the change event also happens without the blur for a select.  However, in context of the question asking for an event that happens before the change event, the answer still holds so I'll leave it for now.  @RoryMcCrossan